# using jquery.val() function is returning undefined and javaScript querySelector is returning null but I want undefined as a return value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a querySelector in a function which is retuning null while the function using jquery for selection return undefined and it works fine after wards so I wanted to use vanilla javaScript not the jquery for slection but want undefined in return when empty collection detected.

```
function manage_cart(pid,type){
    if(type=='update'){
        var qty= document.getElementById(pid+"qty").value;
    }else{
        var qty=  document.getElementById('qty').value;
    
    }
```

this above code is returning null in the else part this not complete code cant write complete due to stackoverflow
below the same returning undefined when using jquery.val() as empty collection detected in else part

```
function manage_cart(pid,type){
    if(type=='update'){
        var qty= document.getElementById(pid+"qty").value;
    }else{
    
    var qty=jQuery("#qty").val();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can set a default value using the `||` operator.**

Implemented your example:

```js
function manage_cart(pid, type) {
    if (type == "update") {
        var qty = document.getElementById(pid + "qty").value || undefined;
    } else {
        var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value || undefined;
    }
}
```

If `document.getElementById()` returns `null`, the value of `qty` will default to `undefined`.

```js
console.log("If null is returned qty will be set to", null || undefined)

console.log("If a value is returned qty will be set to", "the value" || undefined)
```